# How to get access to additional SDKs within a Visual Studio project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sdk

I am trying to have access to the following SDK within my VS C# Project Dependencies/SDKs...

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Asp (2.1.1)

How do I install it?  Otherwise I have to install various Nuget libraries that are already accessible via that SDK.

I know this because I have an existing VS solution with a project that has it. It's the same computer so it has to be Project level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the reference to your `csproj` and restore:

```
dotnet add ./proj.csproj package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Asp -v 2.1.1
dotnet restore
```

Comment: Where is that run from?  the same directory as the csproj with the VS command line?

Comment: @John Where your `csproj` file lives for the project, yes.

Comment: Oh wait it can be added via Nuget!  Thanks!